# Office 365 Graph - "name" property removed from recent files query

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

This morning we have noticed that the "name" property has been removed from the recent files query on the Office 365 Graph API, which is causing issues in our application.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$top=6

There has been no announcement of this change in the documentation or changelog, so I assume this was an unintended change / bug. The filename is arguably the most important property of a file, so this query becomes significantly less useful without that information.

Would someone from the Graph API team please advise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug. The issue should be resolved now. I'm seeing the name parameter be returned from a call to /me/drive/recent currently. Let me know if you're still seeing this.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your response. I'm afraid I'm still not seeing the name of the files come back in Graph API. Please let me know if you need any more information that would help you investigate the issue.

Comment: Hi David. The fix is still rolling out to farms in SharePoint, and is about 80% deployed. It should complete deployment over the next day or two.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - it's fixed now :)